# left-adjoint to join in a Heyting algebra

Tags: logic, category-theory, lattice-orders, heyting-algebra

Define a Heyting algebra to be a bounded lattice $L$ with an operation $\to : L^{op}\times L \to L$ such that for any $x, a, b \in L$ we have $x\wedge a \leqslant b$ iff $x \leqslant a \to b$.  Thinking of $L$ as a category, this says $-\wedge a$ is left-adjoint to $a\to -$. Since $\wedge$ is the product and $\vee$ the coproduct on $L$, we get the distributivity law

$$ a\wedge(b\vee c) = (a\wedge b)\vee (a \wedge c)$$

by abstract nonsense (left adjoints preserve colimits).  This question is about proving the other distributivity law

$$ a \vee (b \wedge c) = (a \vee b) \wedge (a \vee c).$$

If we knew that $a \vee -$ was a right adjoint then this would be immediate as right adjoints preserve limits.  **Is it true that in a Heyting algebra, $a \vee -$ is always a right adjoint?**  If so, what is its left adjoint?
If not, I'm interested in counterexamples or characterisations of those Heyting algebras in which it is true.  I don't see this in the obvious sources ([ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra)) which deal with the second distributivity law by appealing to standard results about duality in distributive lattices or leaving it as an exercise.

---

Comment: Is your question equivalent to whether $$b\leq a\vee x \;\text{iff}\; a\to b\leq x,$$ or something similar?

Comment: @amrsa my question is whether $a \vee -$ always has a left adjoint.  I'm not proposing or ruling out any specific form for that adjoint (and if I had to guess I'd say it didn't always exist).  I don't think what you've written can be true - even in a Boolean algebra it seems wrong.

Comment: Yep, it would be wrong! What I was asking was if there is some equivalence like that you were looking for. Now if that left adjoint might have a form or another, and not a specific one, then I just don't know...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably know this already, but distributivity of $\vee$ over $\wedge$ in a lattice follows easily from distributivity of $\wedge$ over $\vee$:
\begin{align*}
(a\vee b)\wedge (a\vee c) &= ((a\vee b)\wedge a)\vee ((a\vee b)\wedge c)\\
&= a \vee ((a\wedge c)\vee (b\wedge c))\\
&= (a \vee (a \wedge c)) \vee (b \wedge c)\\
&= a \vee (b\wedge c).
\end{align*}
So if you know that $a\wedge -$ is a left adjoint, you actually get both distributive laws "for free".

To answer your actual question, $a\vee -$ is *not* always a right adjoint. For a counterexample, you just need to find a Heyting algebra in which $a\vee -$ fails to preserve some *infinite* meets. In his answer to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/155508/2126), Andreas Blass gives a nice example: Consider the Heyting algebra of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $a = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, and let $b_n = (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$. Then $a\vee \left(\bigwedge_{n\in \mathbb{N}^+} b_n\right) = a$ but $\bigwedge_{n\in \mathbb{N}^+} (a\vee b_n) = \mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, in a *finite* Heyting algebra, all meets are finite, so $a\lor -$ always preserves all meets. The existence of a left adjoint then follows by the adjoint functor theorem for posets. It is defined by $$L(x) = \bigwedge \{c\mid x\leq a\lor c\}.$$
Of course, verifying that this construction works requires you to know that $\vee$ distributes over $\wedge$. So this is not a route to proving the second distributive law, even in finite Heyting algebras.